# Get the Alphabetic Maximum

Tags: microsoft-excel

If there is a word in **A1** and another word in **A2**, I can determine the "greater" by using:

```
=IF(A2>A1,A2,A1)
```

In cell **B2**.  Here "greater" means if the data were sorted ascending, the value would be at the bottom:

[image]

So Whale is below Cloud.

I can extend this approach downwards.  So if there was data in **A3** and below, in **B3** I enter:

```
=IF(B2>A3,B2,A3)
```

and copy down:

[image]

So Zygote is the "greatest" value.  Now if I had numbers rather than words in **A1** thru **A11**, I wouldn't need all these "helper" cells.  I could just use:

```
=MAX(A1:A11)
```

My question:  Is there a single-cell formula that returns the "greatest" word equivalent to *MAX()* for numbers ??

Comment: Check this article out - [Finding the Maximal/ Minimal String, Based on Alphabetic Order in Microsoft Excel 2010](http://www.exceltip.com/lookup-formulas/finding-the-maximal-minimal-string-based-on-alphabetic-order.html#comment-6743). I couldn't get it to work, but maybe you can. Or it will get you close to what you need.

Comment: @CharlieRB  Thanks for the reference...........sadly, I does not work for me either.

Comment: You can't just copy-paste the formula because the quotes have been changed to right double quotes and left double quotes.  It should work if you change the quotes to actual quotes.  Try copying this and then pressing CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER: =INDEX(A1:A11,MATCH(MAX(COUNTIF(A1:A11,"<"&A1:A11)),COUNTIF(A1:A11,"<"&A1:A11),0))

Comment: @JasonClement  Strangely, it works if I omit the **,0** on the *Match()* criteria??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Non-array alternative:

`=LOOKUP(1,0/FREQUENCY(1,COUNTIF($A$1:$A$11,">="&$A$1:$A$11)),$A$1:$A$11)`

Note that the 1 as the first argument of FREQUENCY tells the formula to return the *latest* alphabetically. A 2 here would return the second latest alphabetically, etc.

Hence, to be more dynamic, we can replace this 1 with ROWS($1:1):

`=LOOKUP(1,0/FREQUENCY(ROWS($1:1),COUNTIF($A$1:$A$11,">="&$A$1:$A$11)),$A$1:$A$11)`

which means that we can copy the formula down to give the equivalent of an alphabetically-sorted list (from Z-A) of the original values, just as if we had used the in-built sort feature.

Regards